# Не могу зайти в базу данных PostgresQL (проблема подлинности пароля)

Tags: postgresql

Поставил postgresQL на свой пк (Windows). Учусь всякие штуки делать на nestjs. Нужна именно эта база. Проблема: захожу в терминале предварительно выбрав папку где лежит psql

> .\psql -v

на что мне терминал отвечает:

> Пароль пользователя Admin:

Ввожу пароль от своего аккаунта на ПК. И происходит ошибка:

> psql: ошибка: подключиться к серверу "localhost" (127.0.0.1), порту
> 5432 не удалось: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "Admin" не прошёл проверку
> подлинности (по паролю)

Думал может не на той раскладке или Nun Lock зажат. все проверил.
В итоге решил зайти через pgAdmin4 - та же база, только в виде программы с интерфейсом под windows.
Просит пароль. ввожу тот же пароль, все нормально работает.
Нужно именно из строки как то заходить. Есть мысли что не так?

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы:

1. Создать нового пользователя в PgAdmin с помощью запроса **CREATE ROLE** (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/13/sql-createrole).

Пример:

```
CREATE USER davide WITH PASSWORD 'jw8s0F4';
```

После чего уже зная пароль, заходите через терминал используя **psql** (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/13/app-psql)

2. Сбросить пароль примерно таким способом (https://adminotes.ru/sbros-parolya-v-postgresql-na-windows-platformah/)

Comment: Человек же знает пароль - он может логиниться из pgAdmin. Какой-то уж слишком обходной путь. Не работает логин одним пользователем в конкретной программе - создадим нового. Это как если в машине закончился бензин, то купим новую :)

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin -> там вводишь свой пароль и появится стандартное окно Welcome -> в Quick Links будет Add New Server -> там заполняешь и сохраняешь (не обязательно всё, можно заполнить только General, Connetcion). Теперь в консоли сможешь подключаться к нему. (На всякий случай поясню. При подключение используешь имя и пароль, которые задавал при создании этого сервера)

Answer (score 0):

тоже была такая проблема, с паролем и не находил путь.

решение:

1. прописал путь в переменных средах.
2. Работает только через командную строку, через PowerShell не работает (у меня)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Выполни в консоли:
psql -U postgres
затем введи пароль, который вводил, когда заходил через pgAdmin4. Должно помочь.
Через консоль ты логинешься через системную учетку, которой нет в postgres.
Команда "psql -U USERNAME" позволяет авторизоваться под учеткой USERNAME.
Надеюсь поможет.